# My commits dont count as contribution even though it updates the repository

Tags: git, github, commit

I did commit and push my code changes to github repository from VS code ,but still it doesnt count as my contribution ,but in repository commits I can see the commit

here I have double check the solution :
1.My email connected repository is correct
2. My repository is public not private
3. I have pushed on master branch
4. My repository updates the changes
5. The code changes are major nor minor

I have waited couple of days to count as contribution
still I cant see any green box

Here are the commands I used

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "commit messagr"
3. git push origin master (or I use the push from 3dot in VScode )

How to fix this issue ,is it a github bug ?

Comment: Whose repository is it? Does it need a merge or approval?

Comment: It is my repo and it does not need any merge or approval 
here is the repo link 
https://github.com/1804049Shorna/todo

Comment: Did you check if the other answer (marked as duplicate) answers your question?